# Windows Bluetooth ON/OFF API

Tags: windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I enumerate Bluetooth LE devices using WinRT API, sometimes, I needed to reset Bluetooth radio to successfully find my device. I am wondering is there an easy way to do this from code (Windows SDK, WinRT, WMI etc)?
[image: Highlighted in red, the switch to toggle the radio]

Answer (score 1):

After digging through [Windows Universal samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples) from Microsoft, I have found a sample [RadioManager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/RadioManager) which shows how to access Radios and turn ON/OFF from code at will. I was able to use the API successfully with a caveat that when used from Desktop WPF app, the app has to be built to match native architecture of the machine. Otherwise, ‘GetRadiosAsync’ method returns empty set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but resetting the system-wide Bluetooth radio is the sort of  action highly unlikely to be available to an execution environment with non-admin privileges.

Anything able to stomp over the abilities of other processes (like turning off a radio) is not going to available in WinRT.

Edit: I stand corrected. Such an API apparently exists:

[Windows.Devices.Radios.SetStateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radio#Windows_Devices_Radios_Radio_SetStateAsync_Windows_Devices_Radios_RadioState_)